# boost::asio + std::future - Access violation after closing socket

Tags: c++, c++11, asynchronous, boost-asio

I am writing a simple tcp client to send and receive single lines of text. The asynchronous operations are handled by std::future in order to faciliate blocking queries with timeouts. Unfortunately, my test application crashes with an access violation when destructing the server object.
Here is my code:

TCPClient.hpp

```
#ifndef __TCPCLIENT_H__
#define __TCPCLIENT_H__

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/use_future.hpp>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <future>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

using namespace boost::asio;

class TCPClient {
public:
    TCPClient();
    ~TCPClient();

    void connect(const std::string& address, const std::string& port);
    void disconnect();

    std::string sendMessage(const std::string& msg);
private:
    boost::asio::io_service ioservice;
    boost::asio::io_service::work work;
    std::thread t;

    std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> socket;
};

inline TCPClient::TCPClient() : ioservice(), work(ioservice) {
    t = std::thread([&]() {
        try {
            ioservice.run();
        }
        catch (const boost::system::system_error& e) {
            std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        }
    });
}

inline TCPClient::~TCPClient() {
    disconnect();
    ioservice.stop();
    if (t.joinable()) t.join();
}

inline void TCPClient::connect(const std::string& address, const std::string& port) {
    socket.reset(new ip::tcp::socket(ioservice));

    ip::tcp::resolver::query query(address, port);
    std::future<ip::tcp::resolver::iterator> conn_result = async_connect(*socket, ip::tcp::resolver(ioservice).resolve(query), use_future);

    if (conn_result.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(6)) != std::future_status::timeout) {
        conn_result.get(); // throws boost::system::system_error if the operation fails
    }
    else {
        //socket->close();
        // throw timeout_error("Timeout");
        throw std::exception("timeout");
    }
}

inline void TCPClient::disconnect() {
    if (socket) {
        try {
            socket->shutdown(ip::tcp::socket::shutdown_both);
            std::cout << "socket points to " << std::addressof(*socket) << std::endl;
            socket->close();
        }
        catch (const boost::system::system_error& e) {
            // ignore
            std::cerr << "ignored error " << e.what() << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

inline std::string TCPClient::sendMessage(const std::string& msg) {
    auto time_over = std::chrono::system_clock::now() + std::chrono::seconds(4);

    /*
    // Doesn't affect the error
    std::future<size_t> write_fut = boost::asio::async_write(*socket, boost::asio::buffer(msg), boost::asio::use_future);

    try {
        write_fut.get();
    }
    catch (const boost::system::system_error& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    */
    boost::asio::streambuf response;

    std::future<std::size_t> read_fut = boost::asio::async_read_until(*socket, response, '\n', boost::asio::use_future);
    if (read_fut.wait_until(time_over) != std::future_status::timeout) {
        std::cout << "read " << read_fut.get() << " bytes" << std::endl;
        return std::string(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(&response), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "socket points to " << std::addressof(*socket) << std::endl;
        throw std::exception("timeout");
    }
}
#endif
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

#include "TCPClient.hpp"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    TCPClient client;
    try {
        client.connect("localhost", "27015");
        std::cout << "Response: " << client.sendMessage("Hello!") << std::endl;
    }
    catch (const boost::system::system_error& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The output is "timeout" as expected (test server sends no data on purpose), but `ioservice.run()` crashes immediately (access violation) after closing the socket in `TCPClient::disconnect()`. Am I doing some memory mismanagment here?

Compiler is MSVC 12.0.31101.00 Update 4 (Visual Studio 2013)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`recvmsg` is receiving into a buffer (`streambuf`) that was freed after throwing the exception in `TCPClient::sendMessage` (line 105, end of scope).

You forgot to cancel the asynchronous operation (`async_read_until`) started in line 97. Fix it:

```
else {
    socket->cancel(); // ADDED
    std::cout << "socket points to " << std::addressof(*socket) << std::endl;
    throw std::runtime_error("timeout");
}
```

Or even, just

```
    socket.reset(); // ADDED
```

Same goes for other timeout paths.

Answer (score 2):

The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33444007/85371) addresses what went wrong.

On a higher level, though, you're using futures, *just* to immediately await their return.

It struck me that this is actually not asynchrony at all, and you should be able to do:

- without threading, and joining
- without `.stop()`
- without `work` and `work.reset()`
- without a explicit constructor or destructor
- without the `unique_ptr<socket>` and the lifetime management that came with it
- without the `future<>`, and the `.get()` and `future_status` checking that come with it

All in all, you can do a lot simpler, e.g. using a simple helper function like this:

```
class TCPClient {
public:
    void        disconnect();
    void        connect(const std::string& address, const std::string& port);
    std::string sendMessage(const std::string& msg);

private:
    using error_code = boost::system::error_code;

    template<typename AllowTime> void await_operation(AllowTime const& deadline_or_duration) {
        using namespace boost::asio;

        ioservice.reset();
        {
            high_resolution_timer tm(ioservice, deadline_or_duration);
            tm.async_wait([this](error_code ec) { if (ec != error::operation_aborted) socket.cancel(); });
            ioservice.run_one();
        }
        ioservice.run();
    }

    boost::asio::io_service      ioservice { };
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket { ioservice };
};
```

E.g. `connect(...)` used to be:

```
socket.reset(new ip::tcp::socket(ioservice));

ip::tcp::resolver::query query(address, port);
std::future<ip::tcp::resolver::iterator> conn_result = async_connect(*socket, ip::tcp::resolver(ioservice).resolve(query), use_future);

if (conn_result.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(6)) != std::future_status::timeout) {
    conn_result.get(); // throws boost::system::system_error if the operation fails
}
else {
    socket->cancel();
    // throw timeout_error("Timeout");
    throw std::runtime_error("timeout");
}
```

It now becomes:

```
async_connect(socket, 
        ip::tcp::resolver(ioservice).resolve({address, port}),
        [&](error_code ec, ip::tcp::resolver::iterator it) { if (ec) throw std::runtime_error(ec.message()); });

await_operation(std::chrono::seconds(6));
```

Like wise, `sendMessage` becomes:

```
streambuf response;
async_read_until(socket, response, '\n', [&](error_code ec, size_t bytes_read) {
        if (ec) throw std::runtime_error(ec.message());
        std::cout << "read " << bytes_read << " bytes" << std::endl;
    });

await_operation(std::chrono::system_clock::now() + std::chrono::seconds(4));

return {std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(&response), {}};
```

Note these are *significantly* simpler. Note, also, that correct exception messages are now thrown, depending on the cause of the failures.

### Full Demo

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/80cf872d50a191c3)</kbd>**

```
#ifndef __TCPCLIENT_H__
#define __TCPCLIENT_H__

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/high_resolution_timer.hpp>
#include <iostream>

class TCPClient {
public:
    void        disconnect();
    void        connect(const std::string& address, const std::string& port);
    std::string sendMessage(const std::string& msg);

private:
    using error_code = boost::system::error_code;

    template<typename AllowTime> void await_operation(AllowTime const& deadline_or_duration) {
        using namespace boost::asio;

        ioservice.reset();
        {
            high_resolution_timer tm(ioservice, deadline_or_duration);
            tm.async_wait([this](error_code ec) { if (ec != error::operation_aborted) socket.cancel(); });
            ioservice.run_one();
        }
        ioservice.run();
    }

    boost::asio::io_service      ioservice { };
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket { ioservice };
};


inline void TCPClient::connect(const std::string& address, const std::string& port) {
    using namespace boost::asio;

    async_connect(socket, 
            ip::tcp::resolver(ioservice).resolve({address, port}),
            [&](error_code ec, ip::tcp::resolver::iterator it) { if (ec) throw std::runtime_error(ec.message()); });

    await_operation(std::chrono::seconds(6));
}

inline void TCPClient::disconnect() {
    using namespace boost::asio;

    if (socket.is_open()) {
        try {
            socket.shutdown(ip::tcp::socket::shutdown_both);
            socket.close();
        }
        catch (const boost::system::system_error& e) {
            // ignore
            std::cerr << "ignored error " << e.what() << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

inline std::string TCPClient::sendMessage(const std::string& msg) {
    using namespace boost::asio;

    streambuf response;
    async_read_until(socket, response, '\n', [&](error_code ec, size_t bytes_read) {
            if (ec) throw std::runtime_error(ec.message());
            std::cout << "read " << bytes_read << " bytes" << std::endl;
        });

    await_operation(std::chrono::system_clock::now() + std::chrono::seconds(4));

    return {std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(&response), {}};
}
#endif

#include <iostream>

//#include "TCPClient.hpp"

int main(/*int argc, char* argv[]*/) {
    TCPClient client;
    try {
        client.connect("127.0.0.1", "27015");
        std::cout << "Response: " << client.sendMessage("Hello!") << std::endl;
    }
    catch (const boost::system::system_error& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

### BONUS

If you want even more convenience, have a generalized callback handler that just raises the exception:

```
struct raise {
    template <typename... A> void operator()(error_code ec, A...) const {
        if (ec) throw std::runtime_error(ec.message()); 
    }
};
```

Now, the bodies become even simpler in absense of lambdas:

```
inline void TCPClient::connect(const std::string& address, const std::string& port) {
    async_connect(socket, ip::tcp::resolver(ioservice).resolve({address, port}), raise());
    await_operation(std::chrono::seconds(6));
}

inline std::string TCPClient::sendMessage(const std::string& msg) {
    streambuf response;
    async_read_until(socket, response, '\n', raise());
    await_operation(std::chrono::system_clock::now() + std::chrono::seconds(4));

    return {std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(&response), {}};
}
```

See the adapted demo: **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/32d3a67b7aab2776)</kbd>** too

Comment: Simplified Asio usage, find everything **[in this Gist](https://gist.github.com/sehe/5ec43b7baa7fb8a15ebf)** (with revision history).

Comment: Thank you very much for this awesome explanation! I'll try it out soon. Accepted your other answer because it directly addresses the mistake i made.

Comment: I see one problem with allocating the socket on the stack, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3073354/4313550 The socket can't be reused after it has been closed.

Comment: @TheBender in that case, don't reuse it after it has been closed :) I'm not sure the claim is very accurate, but it doesn't matter for the sample given (it doesn't reuse after close)