# Check for data with timing?

Tags: c++, tcp, boost-asio

Is there a way to check for data for a certain time in asio?

I have a client with an asio socket which has a Method

```
bool ASIOClient::hasData()
{
    return m_socket->available();
}
```

And i'd like to have some kind of delay here so it checks for data for like 1 second max and returns more ealy. Moreover i don't want to poll it for obvious reason that it meight take a second. The reaseon why i use this is, that i do send data to a client and wait for the respond. If he doesnt respond in a certain time i'd close the socket. Thats what the hasData is mentioned for.

I know that it is nativ possible with an select and an fd_set.

---

The asio Client is created in an Accept method of the server socket class and later used to handle requests and send back data to the one who connected here.

```
int ASIOServer::accept(const bool& blocking)
{
    auto l_sock = std::make_shared<asio::ip::tcp::socket>(m_io_service);
    m_acceptor.accept(*l_sock);
    auto l_client = std::make_shared<ASIOClient>(l_sock);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Prefer [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) to `select`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I am developing for Windows. But i know that i can select with timeout (or here poll). But how can i do this on an Asio socket? Does it have any simelar function for this?

Comment: It is operating system specific. I know nothing about Windows. Ask another question (and tag it with Windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to *attempt to read*.

The usual approach is to define deadlines for all asynchronous operations that could take "long" (or even indefinitely long).

This is quite natural in asynchronous executions:

Just add a deadline timer:

```
 boost::asio::deadline_timer tim(svc);
 tim.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(2));
 tim.async_wait([](error_code ec) {
      if (!ec) // timer was not canceled, so it expired
      {
           socket_.cancel(); // cancel pending async operation
      }
 });
```

If you want to use it with synchronous calls, you can with judicious use of `poll()` instead of `run()`. See this answer: [boost::asio + std::future - Access violation after closing socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33442464/boostasio-stdfuture-access-violation-after-closing-socket/33445833#33445833) which implements a helper `await_operation` that runs a single operations *synchronously* but under a timeout.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I think it is a bit missleading that its cald ASIOClient. Here it is a Clienthandle of a server, so basically a wrapper for writing and reading it does not have its own service.

Comment: And my bad, i missed that i do not use boost i use ASIO as Standalone so there is no deadline_timer if i see that right.

Comment: There should be a deadline_timer. Perhaps you also have a `high_resolution_timer` you can use (which uses c++11 `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`)

Comment: @BennX I have no clue where "ASIOClient" and "Clienthandle" come from. Asio sockets cannot be constructed without a service reference.

Comment: Lets continue here if you have time: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95802/check-for-data-with-timing