# How to simulate boost::asio::write with a timeout

Tags: sockets, boost, boost-asio, tcp

I am trying to simulate `boost::asio::write` with timeout. Or you can say, I am trying to use `boost::asio::async_write` with a timeout.

As I see, `boost::asio::write` blocks until all data has been **written & read** on the other side. This kind of functionality certainly requires a timeout.

**So,** Reading through [this simple answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13126776/asioread-with-timeout) by *Robert Hegner* which demostrates how to do a `boost::asio::async_read` with *timeout*, I am **trying adapt the same logic for write** by doing so:

```
size_t write_data_with_time_out() {

    long time_out_secs = 2;

    boost::optional<boost::system::error_code> timer_result;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer timer(the_socket->get_io_service(), boost::posix_time::seconds(time_out_secs));

    timer.expires_from_now();
    timer.async_wait([&timer_result] (const boost::system::error_code& error) {
        timer_result.reset(error);
    });

    boost::optional<boost::system::error_code> write_result;
    size_t bytes_sent = 0;
    boost::asio::async_write(*the_socket, boost::asio::buffer(the_buffer_to_write, the_buffer_to_write.size()), [&write_result, &bytes_sent] (const boost::system::error_code& error, auto size_received) {

        write_result.reset(error);
        bytes_sent = size_received;
    });

    the_socket->get_io_service().reset();
    while (the_socket->get_io_service().run_one()) {

        if (write_result) {
            timer.cancel();
        }
        else if (timer_result) {
            the_socket->cancel();
        }
    }

    if (*write_result) {
        return 0;
    }

    return bytes_sent;
}
```

**Problem:**
The logic works great for read **but** does not seem to work for write case. *Reason* is that `while (the_socket->get_io_service().run_one())` gets hung after calling `the_socket->cancel()` twice.

*However*, in the read case also `the_socket->cancel()` is called twice & does not hang on the 3rd loop over of the while & returns out. Hence no issues with read.

**Question:**
Is my understanding wrong that same *timeout logic* would work for `boost::asio::async_write` case? I think this same logic should work. There is something wrong I am doing which is what I need a suggestion on.

**Additional info required if possible:**
if `boost::asio::read` & `boost::asio::write` had a timeout parameter. I would not have been writing this extra. Seems like there have been a lot of requests to asio guys to introduce a timeout in their sync read & write functions. Like [this one](https://svn.boost.org/trac10/ticket/2832) here.
**Is** there any scope for asio guys to address this request in near future?

I am doing a sync `boost::asio::read` & `boost::asio::write` on the same socket using a worker thread for which this works superb. All I am missing is this timeout functionality.

**Environment:**
My code runs on `Linux` & `MacOSX` with C++ 14 compiler. This question only concerns **TCP sockets**.

Answer (score 4):

I've written the following helper to await *any* async operation synchronously with a timeout¹:

```
template<typename AllowTime> void await_operation(AllowTime const& deadline_or_duration) {
    using namespace boost::asio;

    ioservice.reset();
    {
        high_resolution_timer tm(ioservice, deadline_or_duration);
        tm.async_wait([this](error_code ec) { if (ec != error::operation_aborted) socket.cancel(); });
        ioservice.run_one();
    }
    ioservice.run();
}
```

I've since also demoed that with a full on TCP client: [Boost::Asio synchronous client with timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35818179/boostasio-synchronous-client-with-timeout/35819277#35819277)

The sample includes write operations and has been completely tested.

### Complete Sample:

Taking the "nicer" example from the original post (the FTP client example shows more realistic usage patterns):

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/32d3a67b7aab2776)</kbd>**

```
#ifndef __TCPCLIENT_H__
#define __TCPCLIENT_H__

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/high_resolution_timer.hpp>
#include <iostream>

class TCPClient {
public:
    void        disconnect();
    void        connect(const std::string& address, const std::string& port);
    std::string sendMessage(const std::string& msg);

private:
    using error_code = boost::system::error_code;

    template<typename AllowTime> void await_operation(AllowTime const& deadline_or_duration) {
        using namespace boost::asio;

        ioservice.reset();
        {
            high_resolution_timer tm(ioservice, deadline_or_duration);
            tm.async_wait([this](error_code ec) { if (ec != error::operation_aborted) socket.cancel(); });
            ioservice.run_one();
        }
        ioservice.run();
    }

    struct raise {
        template <typename... A> void operator()(error_code ec, A...) const {
            if (ec) throw std::runtime_error(ec.message()); 
        }
    };

    boost::asio::io_service      ioservice { };
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket { ioservice };
};

inline void TCPClient::disconnect() {
    using namespace boost::asio;

    if (socket.is_open()) {
        try {
            socket.shutdown(ip::tcp::socket::shutdown_both);
            socket.close();
        }
        catch (const boost::system::system_error& e) {
            // ignore
            std::cerr << "ignored error " << e.what() << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

inline void TCPClient::connect(const std::string& address, const std::string& port) {
    using namespace boost::asio;

    async_connect(socket, ip::tcp::resolver(ioservice).resolve({address, port}), raise());

    await_operation(std::chrono::seconds(6));
}

inline std::string TCPClient::sendMessage(const std::string& msg) {
    using namespace boost::asio;

    streambuf response;
    async_read_until(socket, response, '\n', raise());

    await_operation(std::chrono::system_clock::now() + std::chrono::seconds(4));

    return {std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(&response), {}};
}
#endif

#include <iostream>

//#include "TCPClient.hpp"

int main(/*int argc, char* argv[]*/) {
    TCPClient client;
    try {
        client.connect("127.0.0.1", "27015");
        std::cout << "Response: " << client.sendMessage("Hello!") << std::endl;
    }
    catch (const boost::system::system_error& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

---

¹ originally written for this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33445833/85371

Comment: looks like, I need to call `service.await_operation(TIMEOUT, s)` in the lambda passed into the last argument of `boost::asio::async_write` ?

Comment: Is it possible to just put a code piece demonstrating how your service can be used in the code sample I have put up? **If possible**, for the completeness of context in this question

Comment: I think I linked to two answers that had complete, live examples. I opted to not to copy them here. If you prefer, I can :)

Comment: yes. I would prefer if you could copy the code required in the context of this question. it would make this discussion look complete. meanwhile, I am figuring out how to use your service time out op

Comment: deleted my previous question which was rather naive. whenever I `async_write` or `async_read`, I need to follow it up the call to `await_operation(std::chrono::seconds(number_of_secs))` for example. thats all I need from your code to try out at least.

Comment: I think there is an inherent problem with my code. there is something I am doing seriously wrong. not sure what. when the call comes inside `await_operation`, then `m_io_service.run()` gets called & never returns. really strange. Neither do I get a callback to the lambda I passed into `async_write` not does control reach the line following `await_operation`. **Do point out if you see anything wrong with the way I am calling** `async_write` in the code I have provided in my question.

Comment: @TitoHamzee can you post a minimal, self-contained example? I have no clue how you instantiate the `io_service`. You might have something like `io_service::work` declared, but we can't see.

Comment: I dont have any `io_service::work`  declared. my code is a part of a library which is very separate from the application. its almost impossible to post the code from there to form a self-contained example. **but still, I will try to**. basically I was using sync read & write calls with a worker thread assigned on both client & server sides which worked all fine to read & fetch data on both sides on one tcp socket. Now trying to replace them with async calls. the `async_read` works but struggling to replace `write` with `async_write`.

Comment: why `TCPClient::sendMessage` actually receives data?

Comment: @Gruffalo did you mean to comment at the question?

Comment: @sehe: sorry, finally found it, the original question had writing part commented out

Comment: why is your sendMessage calling async_read_until? I am looking for a solution to do async_write with a timeout since a regular write does not allow one. This is "fire and forget" and doesn't read anything

Comment: @CashCow The better question is "why doesn't `sendMessage` send `msg`" - I have no idea, I cannot find the code it was based on anymore. To answer the fire and forget, use `asio::detached`. If it's fire and forget you probably don't care about timeouts anyways?