# Is it possible to handle a blocking read function with timeout?

Tags: c++, boost, websocket, boost-asio, boost-beast

I am working on boost websockets for [asynchronous communication between the client and server](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/beast/example/websocket/client/async-ssl/websocket_client_async_ssl.cpp).

Now I am printing the **time elapsed** during the program with `boost::timer::auto_cpu_timer`. It is displaying the time elapsed in seconds.

My program snippet is given below:

This function **sends** the data to the websocket:

```
void WebSocketSession::WriteSocket(beast::error_code ec) {
    if (ec)
         return fail(ec, "ssl_handshake");
    cout << "Authorised" <<endl;
    
    //Start the timer
    BoostTimer.start();
    
    // Send the Data message
    ws_.async_write(net::buffer(DATAMSG),
            bind(&WebSocketSession::ReadSocket, shared_from_this(), placeholders::_1,placeholders::_2));
}
```

This function **reads** the websocket response

```
void WebSocketSession::ReadSocket(beast::error_code ec, size_t bytes_transferred) {
    boost::ignore_unused(bytes_transferred);
    if (ec)
         return fail(ec, "WriteSocket Failed");

    cout << "Time Elapsed before reading WS : " << TimeElapsed() << endl;

    try {
        ws_.read(ReadBuffer_);
    } catch (exception *e) {
        cerr << "Error: " << e->what() << endl;
    }

    cout << "Time Elapsed after reading WS : " << TimeElapsed() << endl;
    
    // Display the buffer into stringstream
    cout << beast::buffers(ReadBuffer_.data());
    
    // Clear the websocket buffer
    ReadBuffer_.consume(ReadBuffer_.size());

    cout << "Time Elapsed before moving ahead : " << TimeElapsed() << endl;

    // Decision tree

    // IsGstFileWriteDone() gives "true" when the file is written... that file is not related to this context. An event is pushed saying FILE_WRITE_DONE
        if (mIbmWatsonobj->IsGstFileWriteDone()){
            cout<< "Going to CloseSocket" << endl;
            WebSocketSession::CloseSocket(ec, 0);
        }else{
            cout<< "Going to ReadSocket" << endl;
            WebSocketSession::ReadSocket(ec, 0);
        }
}
```

This function **closes** the web socket

```
void WebSocketSession::CloseSocket(beast::error_code ec, size_t bytes_transferred) {
    boost::ignore_unused(bytes_transferred);
    if (ec)
        return fail(ec, "ReadSocket Failed");

    cout << "CLOSING" <<endl;
    
    // Close the WebSocket connection
    ws_.close(websocket::close_code::normal);
}
```

Here is how my program output looks like: The response received from websocket is shown in grey (output of `cout << beast::buffers(ReadBuffer_.data());`) rest are couts printed at various places in program. **The time elapsed is in seconds**

> IBM Authorised
> Time Elapsed before reading WS : 0
> Time Elapsed after reading WS : 0.3
>
> ```
> {  
>     "state": "listening"  
> }
> ```
>
> Time Elapsed before moving ahead : 0.3
> Going to ReadSocket
> Time Elapsed before reading WS : 0.3
> Time Elapsed after reading WS : 2.1
>
> ```
> {
>    "results": [
>       {
>          "alternatives": [
>             {
>                "confidence": 0.89, 
>                "transcript": "several tornadoes touch down as a line of severe some "
>             }
>          ], 
>          "final": true
>       }
>    ], 
>    "result_index": 0
> }
> ```
>
> Time Elapsed before moving ahead : 2.1
> Going to ReadSocket
> Time Elapsed before reading WS : 2.1
> Time Elapsed after reading WS : 2.1
>
> ```
> {
>    "state": "listening"
> }
> ```
>
> Time Elapsed before moving ahead : 2.1
> Going to ReadSocket
> Time Elapsed before reading WS : 2.1
>
> Event pushed : FILE_WRITE_DONE
>
> Time Elapsed after reading WS : 34
>
> ```
> {
>    "error": "Session timed out."
> }
> ```
>
> Time Elapsed before moving ahead : 34
>
> //PROGRAM EXITS WITH -1

**Question:**

After `2.1` seconds the program goes to ReadSocket again where the `ws_.read(ReadBuffer_);` is blocking the execution for almost 32secs untill it receives something from socket, in this case it receives the "session timeout".

How can I move to the CloseSocket while this block is on for say 5 sec. That is if at any point of time I have `ws_.read` blocking my code for more than 5 sec I want to put my behaviour, say CloseSocket.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47378022/how-to-simulate-boostasiowrite-with-a-timeout/47381372#47381372

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you can just use the new Boost.Beast in 1.70.0 which supports built-in timeouts on websocket operations: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/using_websocket/timeouts.html

Comment: Hi @VinnieFalco Yes that works with the 1.70.0 and 1.68.0 as well ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55708200/10862144))