# how to cancel a `boost::asio::read` operation while it's waiting

Tags: c++, sockets, boost-asio

I am using `boost::asio` to transfer data to & fro from client to server. I have a reader thread on client side to read data received on the socket on client side. Please note that I am using `boost::asio::read` on client side & `boost::asio::write`on server side. 
Not using `async_read` or `async_write`. Everything works great.

However when I close my application, 2 out 10 times the app does not cleanly tear down or close properly. It gets hung while closing down The issue is the following:

My closing function gets called when destructors get called during my app's close down. Following is the code of the Close function:

```
socket.cancel();
socket.close();
boost::system::error_code ec;
socket.shutdown(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::shutdown_both, ec);
```

The problem is that the `boost::asio::read` call does not return when it does not get any data & keeps waiting on it. This should be fine as long as I can cancel it. I am trying to do a `socket.cancel` on it to cancel all read operations while exiting. 
However, it doesn't seems to work. I read in some forums that `socket.cancel` only cancels `async_read` operations. Is it so ? **Then what is the way to cancel a boost::asio::read` operation when my app needs to exit ?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's the nature of blocking IO.

Indeed `socket.cancel()` (or even `io_service::stop()`) will not work on synchronous operations.

The only way to interrupt this is to use socket-level timeouts (but Asio doesn't expose that) or to use asynchronous signals (e.g. pressing Ctrl-C in a terminal sends the child process a SIGINT).

I've previously created a poor-man's wrapper if you insist on running single operations with a timeout:

- [boost::asio + std::future - Access violation after closing socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33442464/boostasio-stdfuture-access-violation-after-closing-socket/33445833#33445833)

Comment: Seems like I need use async operations to resolve this issue. My C++ which hosts this code is getting used in UI based apps & it is not a problem there because I think the `SIGINT` is sent to kill the whole app when the UI app gets killed. It is only a problem when the client app is a console app. Anyways, thanks for this explanation

Answer (score 0):

```
boost::system::error_code _error_code;
client_socket_->shutdown(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::shutdown_both, _error_code);
```

Above code help me close sync read immediately.
And sync read wiil return with error code: boost::asio::error::eof
I wonder why your code `socket.shutdown(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::shutdown_both, ec);` did not work.

Maybe you should try again.

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to the call to `socket.close()` before the call to `socket.shutdown()`. If you close a socket while there is a pending synchronous `read()`, you will occasionally get that error. It is really due to an expected data race in the underlying asio socket code.

Try removing the `socket.close()` call. Assuming your socket is wrapped in some kind of shared_ptr, you can let the socket destructor close the underlying socket.

You will still want to call `socket.cancel()` and `socket.shutdown()` explicitly in your use case in order to cancel outstanding operations.