# Can't implement boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> reconnect to server

Tags: c++, sockets, ssl, boost, boost-asio

I need to implement a class which handle connect to ssl server. Pretty much
based on [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/ssl/client.cpp). However. it doesn't have [reconnect feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062803/how-do-i-cleanly-reconnect-a-boostsocket-following-a-disconnect). So I
modify it like this:

```
boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> socket_;
```

to

```
boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> *mpSocket_;
```

and refactor everything related to `->`

But it leads to errors like this:

```
/usr/include/boost/asio/impl/read.hpp:271: error: request for member 'async_read_some' in '((boost::asio::detail::read_op<boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >*, boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1, boost::asio::detail::transfer_all_t, boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf2<void, SSLHandler, const boost::system::error_code&, long unsigned int>, boost::_bi::list3<boost::_bi::value<SSLHandler*>, boost::arg<1> (*)(), boost::arg<2> (*)()> > >*)this)->boost::asio::detail::read_op<boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >*, boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1, boost::asio::detail::transfer_all_t, boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf2<void, SSLHandler, const boost::system::error_code&, long unsigned int>, boost::_bi::list3<boost::_bi::value<SSLHandler*>, boost::arg<1> (*)(), boost::arg<2> (*)()> > >::stream_', which is of pointer type 'boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >*' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)
          stream_.async_read_some(
          ^

/usr/include/boost/asio/impl/write.hpp:258: error: request for member 'async_write_some' in '((boost::asio::detail::write_op<boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >*, boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1, boost::asio::detail::transfer_all_t, boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf2<void, SSLHandler, const boost::system::error_code&, long unsigned int>, boost::_bi::list3<boost::_bi::value<SSLHandler*>, boost::arg<1> (*)(), boost::arg<2> (*)()> > >*)this)->boost::asio::detail::write_op<boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >*, boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1, boost::asio::detail::transfer_all_t, boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf2<void, SSLHandler, const boost::system::error_code&, long unsigned int>, boost::_bi::list3<boost::_bi::value<SSLHandler*>, boost::arg<1> (*)(), boost::arg<2> (*)()> > >::stream_', which is of pointer type 'boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >*' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)
          stream_.async_write_some(
          ^
```

Then I tried to dereference the pointer to keep the old structure but there's new error :(

```
boost::asio::async_connect(*socket_.lowest_layer(), mEndpointIterator, boost::bind(&SSLHandler::handle_connect, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
error: request for member 'lowest_layer' in '((SSLHandler*)this)->SSLHandler::socket_', which is of pointer type 'boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >*' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)
     boost::asio::async_connect(*socket_.lowest_layer(), mEndpointIterator, boost::bind(&SSLHandler::handle_connect, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));`
```

Please help, I'm coming from java so it's quite complicated with me this thing.

Comment: It would help to see your actual code. Regarding your second compilation error: `*socket_.lowest_layer()` should be `(*socket_).lowest_layer()`.

Comment: Please post code where the errors occur / create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: "and refactor everything related to ->" - clearly you didn't do that correctly. Why would you need to use a pointer anyways? That's a X/Y problem to begin with.

Comment: Thank you for the attention. It's my bad that I missed one `socket` not change to `*socket`.
@sehe:  Please read [this] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062803/how-do-i-cleanly-reconnect-a-boostsocket-following-a-disconnect). Once you close the socket, you can't reopen it again :(

Comment: @Patton even that answer recognizes there is no need for a raw pointer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is my minimal change to that demo in Boost 1.66.0. See the patch in isolation on github: https://github.com/boostorg/asio/compare/develop...sehe:so-q49122521

> Note: I moved the address resolve into the connect sequence, because if the network configuration has been changed, the result may differ, or another one of the endpoints should be preferred.
>
> For this end, we store a `resolver::query query_` member so we can repeat the query on reconnect.

```
//
// client.cpp
// ~~~~~~~~~~
//
// Copyright (c) 2003-2018 Christopher M. Kohlhoff (chris at kohlhoff dot com)
//
// Distributed under the Boost Software License, Version 1.0. (See accompanying
// file LICENSE_1_0.txt or copy at http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)
//

#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>

enum { max_length = 1024 };

class client
{
public:
  client(boost::asio::io_context& io_context,
      boost::asio::ssl::context& context,
      boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query)
    : socket_(io_context, context), query_(query), timer_(io_context)
  {
    socket_.set_verify_mode(boost::asio::ssl::verify_peer);
    socket_.set_verify_callback(
        boost::bind(&client::verify_certificate, this, _1, _2));

    start_connect();
  }

  void start_connect() {
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver r(socket_.get_io_context());

    boost::asio::async_connect(socket_.lowest_layer(), r.resolve(query_),
        boost::bind(&client::handle_connect, this,
          boost::asio::placeholders::error));
  }

  void do_reconnect() {
    timer_.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::millisec(500));
    timer_.async_wait(boost::bind(&client::handle_reconnect_timer, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
  }

  void handle_reconnect_timer(boost::system::error_code ec) {
    if (!ec) {
      start_connect();
    }
  }

  bool verify_certificate(bool preverified,
      boost::asio::ssl::verify_context& ctx)
  {
    // The verify callback can be used to check whether the certificate that is
    // being presented is valid for the peer. For example, RFC 2818 describes
    // the steps involved in doing this for HTTPS. Consult the OpenSSL
    // documentation for more details. Note that the callback is called once
    // for each certificate in the certificate chain, starting from the root
    // certificate authority.

    // In this example we will simply print the certificate's subject name.
    char subject_name[256];
    X509* cert = X509_STORE_CTX_get_current_cert(ctx.native_handle());
    X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(cert), subject_name, 256);
    std::cout << "Verifying " << subject_name << "\n";

    return preverified;
  }

  void handle_connect(const boost::system::error_code& error)
  {
    if (!error)
    {
      socket_.async_handshake(boost::asio::ssl::stream_base::client,
          boost::bind(&client::handle_handshake, this,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }
    else
    {
      std::cout << "Connect failed: " << error.message() << "\n";
      do_reconnect();
    }
  }

  void accept_message() {
      std::cout << "Enter message: ";
      std::cin.getline(request_, max_length);
      size_t request_length = strlen(request_);

      boost::asio::async_write(socket_,
          boost::asio::buffer(request_, request_length),
          boost::bind(&client::handle_write, this,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error,
            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }

  void handle_handshake(const boost::system::error_code& error)
  {
    if (!error)
    {
      accept_message();
    }
    else
    {
      std::cout << "Handshake failed: " << error.message() << "\n";
      do_reconnect();
    }
  }

  void handle_write(const boost::system::error_code& error,
      size_t bytes_transferred)
  {
    if (!error)
    {
      boost::asio::async_read(socket_,
          boost::asio::buffer(reply_, bytes_transferred),
          boost::bind(&client::handle_read, this,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error,
            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }
    else
    {
      std::cout << "Write failed: " << error.message() << "\n";
      do_reconnect();
    }
  }

  void handle_read(const boost::system::error_code& error,
      size_t bytes_transferred)
  {
    if (!error)
    {
      std::cout << "Reply: ";
      std::cout.write(reply_, bytes_transferred);
      std::cout << "\n";

      accept_message(); // continue using the same socket_ until fail
    }
    else
    {
      std::cout << "Read failed: " << error.message() << "\n";
      do_reconnect();
    }
  }

private:
  boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> socket_;
  boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query_;
  boost::asio::deadline_timer timer_;
  char request_[max_length];
  char reply_[max_length];
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  try
  {
    if (argc != 3)
    {
      std::cerr << "Usage: client <host> <port>\n";
      return 1;
    }

    boost::asio::io_context io_context;
    boost::asio::ssl::context ctx(boost::asio::ssl::context::sslv23);
    ctx.load_verify_file("ca.pem");

        client c(io_context, ctx, {argv[1], argv[2]});

    io_context.run();
  }
  catch (std::exception& e)
  {
    std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Here it is live demo-ed:

[image]

### Further Thoughts

Depending on your level of paranoia you could feel better actually closing the ssl stream in `do_reconnect()`:

```
boost::system::error_code ec;
socket_.shutdown(ec);
if (ec) std::cout << "shutdown error: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
```

That also works. You could even decide to kill off any lowest level connection just in case:

```
auto& ll = socket_.lowest_layer();

if (ll.is_open())
{
  ll.shutdown(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::shutdown_both, ec);
  //if (ec) std::cout << "socket.shutdown error: " << ec.message() << std::endl;

  ll.close(ec);
  //if (ec) std::cout << "socket.close error: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
}
```

### Using a dynamically allocated socket

As mentioned, the purest solution would be to not reuse the stream/socket objects:

```
boost::optional<stream> socket_;
```

Now, updating all references to indirect `socket_`, `do_reconnect()` can become:

```
void do_reconnect() {
  auto& io_context = socket_->get_io_context();
  {
      boost::system::error_code ec;
      socket_->shutdown(ec);
      if (ec) std::cout << "shutdown error: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
  }

  socket_.emplace(io_context, context_);

  timer_.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::millisec(500));
  timer_.async_wait(boost::bind(&client::handle_reconnect_timer, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
}
```

Which obviously also works.

Here's the corresponding patch: https://github.com/boostorg/asio/compare/develop...sehe:so-q49122521-dynamic

```
//
// client.cpp
// ~~~~~~~~~~
//
// Copyright (c) 2003-2018 Christopher M. Kohlhoff (chris at kohlhoff dot com)
//
// Distributed under the Boost Software License, Version 1.0. (See accompanying
// file LICENSE_1_0.txt or copy at http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)
//

#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>

enum { max_length = 1024 };

namespace ssl = boost::asio::ssl;
using tcp = boost::asio::ip::tcp;

class client
{
    using stream = ssl::stream<tcp::socket>;
public:
  client(boost::asio::io_context& io_context, ssl::context& context, tcp::resolver::query query)
    : context_(context), socket_(boost::in_place_init, io_context, context_), query_(query), timer_(io_context)
  {
    socket_->set_verify_mode(ssl::verify_peer);
    socket_->set_verify_callback(
        boost::bind(&client::verify_certificate, this, _1, _2));

    start_connect();
  }

  void start_connect() {
    tcp::resolver r(socket_->get_io_context());

    boost::asio::async_connect(socket_->lowest_layer(), r.resolve(query_),
        boost::bind(&client::handle_connect, this,
          boost::asio::placeholders::error));
  }

  void do_reconnect() {
    auto& io_context = socket_->get_io_context();
    {
        boost::system::error_code ec;
        socket_->shutdown(ec);
        if (ec) std::cout << "shutdown error: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
    }

    socket_.emplace(io_context, context_);

    timer_.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::millisec(500));
    timer_.async_wait(boost::bind(&client::handle_reconnect_timer, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
  }

  void handle_reconnect_timer(boost::system::error_code ec) {
    if (!ec) {
      start_connect();
    }
  }

  bool verify_certificate(bool preverified,
      ssl::verify_context& ctx)
  {
    // The verify callback can be used to check whether the certificate that is
    // being presented is valid for the peer. For example, RFC 2818 describes
    // the steps involved in doing this for HTTPS. Consult the OpenSSL
    // documentation for more details. Note that the callback is called once
    // for each certificate in the certificate chain, starting from the root
    // certificate authority.

    // In this example we will simply print the certificate's subject name.
    char subject_name[256];
    X509* cert = X509_STORE_CTX_get_current_cert(ctx.native_handle());
    X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(cert), subject_name, 256);
    std::cout << "Verifying " << subject_name << "\n";

    return preverified;
  }

  void handle_connect(const boost::system::error_code& error)
  {
    if (!error)
    {
      socket_->async_handshake(ssl::stream_base::client,
          boost::bind(&client::handle_handshake, this,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }
    else
    {
      std::cout << "Connect failed: " << error.message() << "\n";
      do_reconnect();
    }
  }

  void accept_message() {
    std::cout << "Enter message: ";
    std::cin.getline(request_, max_length);
    size_t request_length = strlen(request_);

    boost::asio::async_write(*socket_,
        boost::asio::buffer(request_, request_length),
        boost::bind(&client::handle_write, this,
          boost::asio::placeholders::error,
          boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
  }

  void handle_handshake(const boost::system::error_code& error)
  {
    if (!error)
    {
      accept_message();
    }
    else
    {
      std::cout << "Handshake failed: " << error.message() << "\n";
      do_reconnect();
    }
  }

  void handle_write(const boost::system::error_code& error,
      size_t bytes_transferred)
  {
    if (!error)
    {
      boost::asio::async_read(*socket_,
          boost::asio::buffer(reply_, bytes_transferred),
          boost::bind(&client::handle_read, this,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error,
            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }
    else
    {
      std::cout << "Write failed: " << error.message() << "\n";
      do_reconnect();
    }
  }

  void handle_read(const boost::system::error_code& error,
      size_t bytes_transferred)
  {
    if (!error)
    {
      std::cout << "Reply: ";
      std::cout.write(reply_, bytes_transferred);
      std::cout << "\n";

      accept_message(); // continue using the same socket_ until fail
    }
    else
    {
      std::cout << "Read failed: " << error.message() << "\n";
      do_reconnect();
    }
  }

private:
  ssl::context& context_;

  boost::optional<stream> socket_;
  tcp::resolver::query query_;
  boost::asio::deadline_timer timer_;
  char request_[max_length];
  char reply_[max_length];
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    try
    {
        if (argc != 3)
        {
            std::cerr << "Usage: client <host> <port>\n";
            return 1;
        }

        boost::asio::io_context io_context;
        ssl::context ctx(ssl::context::sslv23);
        ctx.load_verify_file("ca.pem");

        client c(io_context, ctx, {argv[1], argv[2]});

        io_context.run();
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First of all, thank for the detailed answer. It means very much to me. But which version of boost did you use? I use 1.56 and `boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> socket_;` doesn't have method `get_io_context()`

Comment: See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/net_ts.html. On older versions globally replace `io_context` with `io_service`

Comment: Hi, I have trouble call `boost::system::error_code ec;
      socket_->shutdown(ec);
      if (ec) std::cout << "shutdown error: " << ec.message() << std::endl;` the server and the clients still send and receive messages.

Comment: How would shutting down Ssl in the client stop the server or any other client anyway

Comment: I mean the socket still active ( can read and and write messages). I just make a work around: stop process messages when receive command from upper layer not actually close the socket

Comment: I will post the source soon; it has so many dependencies and bloating things now

Comment: I don't get it. Why did you even need to reconnect, if the connection isn't actually dropped? I specifically modified the example to keep reading/sending messages for the **exact** reason that it doesn't make any sense to "reconnect" a connection that's already connected. (So in my demo, we can keep working until the connection is actually dropped, after which reconnect is initiated).

Comment: If you just want a new connection after each message, unconditionally, just instantiate new `client` instances.

Comment: I forget to mention that it's the extra questions: I want to disconnect the socket when receive a disconnect command from upper layer. The shutdown function didn't terminate the socket

Comment: I already showed that in the answer (_"You could even decide to kill off any lowest level connection just in case:"_...). Again. I'm wondering why, all of a sudden you are worried about "closing the socket". I thought the problem was how to reconnect when the socket malfunctioned all of it's own?! If you want to close the socket, simply start a new client. Period!

Comment: I do read that on the main answer :) But both call socket.shutdown() and socket.lowest_layer().close() don't terminate the socket. (The server still send messages through) I'm scratching my head so hard now :(

Comment: Why are you trying to close the socket? That has **nothing** to do with reconnecting.

Comment: It's an extra question I want to get your opinion.

Comment: Start a new client :) (and for new questions, start a new question, by the way)

Comment: Thank you for spend your time. You're very helpful